# Yeoman webapp scaffolding returning 404 on static resources

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I'm starting to experiment with [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/index.html), but I'm having some issues with the webapp generator. I followed the tutorial on the [homepage](http://yeoman.io/gettingstarted.html), and the application was generated fine. However, after I preview it in the browser (using `grunt server`), the static resources like scripts and styles are returning 404s.

Here is the list of commands I've run:

1. `yo webapp`
2. `grunt build`
3. `grunt server`

The result in the browser looks like basic HTML with no styles and requests for static resources are returning 404:
[image]

The "bower_components" directory is missing. Should it be generated automatically when I build the application? the `.bowerrc` file seems to be the place that references this directory, but I am wondering if I should create it manually or not. I am new to bower, so what's the recommended way to go about this?

All this is running on Windows. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During a successful Yeoman scaffold (during the `yo webapp` process), `bower install` will be run to install all of the dependencies listed in `bower.json`. It's likely something went wrong during the scaffolding process, aborting it before `bower install` could be wrong.

Try running `bower install` from the root directory of your project (where `bower.json` exists), and see if it creates that `app/bower_components` directory.

Comment: Yes, this helped. It seems the the install failed the first time. I had issues that Git was not in the PATH, so that may have been the reason. I was expecting the whole operation to be atomic (don't generate anything if something fails)